# What is the time Complexity of the statement x[-1] where x is a list

Tags: python, list, time-complexity

Assuming x is a list of length n.
What is the time complexity of the operation x[-1]? (which gives the last element of the list).

Comment: What do you think it is? And why?

Comment: Have you tried testing it?

Comment: @wjandrea. This works well as a gedanken problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, [getting an item from a list is `O(1)`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

As a short explanation: the list has its length stored as a property. When you do `x[-1]`, the list calculates the index to grab based on its length, which is a single arithmetic operation. Then, it grabs the memory at that index, which is another single operation. Thus, `O(1)` - the input doesn't really matter for the time complexity of the function. If anything, `lst[-i]` might be a few nanoseconds slower than `lst[i]`, but that's a difference of a couple of lines of code, not of an entire complexity class.